# Unit Testing a method which uses object instances internally

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

While writing the unit testing for class B, how can i test the method -> `checkValidity()`. The method internally initializes class C instance and invokes methods on that object.

How can we check with `Mockito`/`Powermock`?

```
public class B {

 public List<Object> checkValidity(){

   C c=new C();

   if(c.isTrue()){
    .....
   }

   switch(c.getVal()){

       case 1: ...
       case 2: ..
       default : ...

   }



 }

 return list;

}

class C {

  public boolean isTrue(){
    ....
  }


  public int getVal(){
    ....
  }

}
```

Regards

Comment: You could use DI, and pass an interface to the constructor of B that, when called, instanciates an instance of C.  You would then create two separate classes that implement this interface, one for testing and one for the real world.

Comment: We may use more than one obj within a method and all of them can't go into the constructor. We would end up creating lot of objects and then pass it to  this huge list params constructor wherever we are instantiating B. And definitely that would mean we are moving all objects to class level that were earlier within the method.

Comment: Can you just create an instance of B, call `checkValidity()`, and then test the result?  In what way is it a problem that `C` is created internally?  Or is it `C` that you're wanting to test?

Comment: Yes ,we could create an instance of B and call checkValidity but within that method how can we get to control the values returned by C. I may need to validate the result of checkValidity based on different scenarios of C's methods results.

Comment: I see.  I go back to my first comment and recommend an interface to a `C`.  You can then pass a C with whatever values you require.  Classic DI.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide instance of class C as parameter of constructor of class B. That way you can pass mocked instance of that class into class B and verify if method on instance is called and mock its result if needed.

```
public class B {

private final C c;
public B(C c){
    this.c = c;
}

public List<Object> checkValidity(){

   if(c.isTrue()){

   }

  switch(c.getVal()){

   case 1: ...
   case 2: ..
   default : ...

  }

  return list;
}

class C {

  public boolean isTrue(){ }

  public int getVal(){}

}
```

Now you can mock instance of C with mockito.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating an interface only for the purpose of testing. This is a test class in production. You don't need that. Mockito can mock classes.

Comment: But above would mean modifying your class to make it work for testing. Also am changing the scope of c from local/method level to instance level which may not be desirable for every situation.

Comment: If you have to test static method you could extract static method call in separate method. Lets call it `methodA()`. Then in your test class you should create inner class that extends B and overrides that extracted method and provide default value you want. Then you test that new inner class and you have mocked value for that `methodA()`.

Comment: But it would mean , I would be modifying the actual class to help with testing which I cant be able to do. Need to keep the B class without any modifications

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is externalize creation of object C into package-private method, instead of :

`C c = new C();`

You can use:

`C c = createC();`

Afterwards you should be able to use mockito Spy and overwrite returned argument by some mock. Something like

`doReturn(mockedCObject).when(objectUnderTest.createC());`

Comment: The code is an existing one and so we would need to do something in the test class itself.

Comment: Without any modification it will be very hard (impossible I guess) to do that without PowerMock. This small modification is quite safe, but If you can not edit the code it wont work...